# How to embed youtube channel with thumbnails with over 4000 videos

Tags: web, video, youtube, embed, youtube-channels

I am trying to embed a youtube channel onto a website  with thumbnails for customer, but it tells me that i can only embed up to 500 videos.

The channel has over 4000 videos and need them all embedded!

Is this possible?

Hope to hear from someone soon!

Jordan

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and the errors you're facing

Comment: Im using a wordpress plugin called TubePress, after checking with their support it does state that only 500 videos are viewable. Do you know a way to do this without the need for a plug in?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, till using this code:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&up_channel=**yourchannelname**&synd=open&output=js&w=**350**&h=**355**"></script>
```

but, since last week it doenst work for me,
Perharps you are more lucky